# Coldfusion COM not registered

Tags: dll, coldfusion

First time ever using ColdFusion.

We have a website that uses ColdFusion 9 on our live server.  It calls a COM DLL to encrypt certain things. The code on our live server works fine.

Since I may be taking over the project I installed ColdFusion 10 Developer edition on my local machine and copied all the source code and DLL's down to my local machine for testing.

I am getting an error that it can't instantiate the COM object because it is not registered but I KNOW it is registered because the DLL works on other parts of our website that are still in Classic ASP and will run on my local machine.  I actually wrote a ASP script inside the the ColdFusion test site on my machine to test the DLL and everything works fine so it IS registered (via regsvr32.exe).

The ColdFusion page was done by an outside company that we are going to be breaking ties with and I don't have the password to their ColdFusion control panel even though it is on one of our servers.  I wanted to look at their settings.  Is there some setting that I need to set in the control panel on my machine?  If there is I haven't found it yet.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here is the code:

```
<cfscript>
    objEnc = CreateObject("com", "mycom.myclass");
</cfscript>
```

Also, I am running the 32-bit version of CF on a Windows 7 Pro 64-bit OS.

EDIT:

Another edit just for some more info:

The Windows 2008R2 server that it runs successfully on is a 64-bit server.  So OS shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Should I try to find Version 9 developer edition on adobe's site and see if it works since it matches the CF version on the server?  Haven't been able to find that yet and now Adobe just released 11.

Comment: can you show the code that instantiates the COM?

Comment: Is the com object being used as custom tag?

Comment: And you've registered the DLL under the CF Admin >> Extensions >> CFX Tags >> Register C++ Tag

Comment: Are you running 64-bit ColdFusion? I believe COM is only supported on 32-bit.

Comment: @Miguel-F - If I go into Register C++ Tag I get and error saying that I need to configure the server to enable native CFX support.

Comment: And if you [just Google that](http://bit.ly/1koGOFZ) you will find your answer. The short of it is that the compat c++ libraries must be installed so the C++ CFXs can be registered. [Reference, page 29, step 11](http://cf.giss.com.br/repository/installing-adobe-coldfusion-9.pdf) - _11 To use cfregistry in Windows, to use the cfreport tag for Crystal Reports, and to use any **C++ CFX custom tags**, add cfusion/lib to the Java library path. Add the following directory to the JVM’s native library path (java.library.path): `WEB-INF/cfusion/lib`_

Comment: To ALL... the code above has nothing to do with CFX. CFX is an interface library allowing allowing to write or wrap code in C++ or Java. The code above uses the COM interface (old style MS object libraries) through the JINI process.  The most likely issue here is 64bit vs 32bit. Getting COM to work on any platform above CF5 has been dicey because of the switch to Java in the underlying engine.

Comment: Good point @MarkAKruger. I was basing my replies off a previous comment and got off track. Thanks for clearing things up.

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing that up, as a CF newbie I thought maybe the DLL did have to be "registered" with ColdFusion also.

Comment: Would it be because the DLL is registered under a different user than what CF is running on?

Comment: If you're looking for the CF 9 downloads you can still get them via http://www.gpickin.com/index.cfm/blog/cfml-server-a-different-type-of-coldfusion-repo-coldfusion-installs or http://www.dcepler.net/post.cfm/last-day-to-download-cf-8-and-9-from-adobe-with-verity

Answer (score 1):

After downgrading my local machine to ColdFusion 9 I can now access the COM DLL perfectly.  Which is probably for the best since our server is running CF9.  My testing will be with same version.  Thanks for all you guy's input.

Randy